# How can I hide Media Libraries in Kentico 11.

Tags: kentico

I have a site with many media libraries and am setting up different users who will have access to different libraries.  It seems that no matter what i do, someone that has access to the media libraries sees all the different media libraries even though they are not set in the permissions to view them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly set up security on EACH media library.  The best way to do this is to go into each media library and restrict everyone from that library by going to the Security tab, then at the top select Authorized Roles for all 7 columns.  Then below select the authorized roles allowed to perform each action.

All users should have permission to see the Media Library App but the content within it is limited by individual security on each of the libraries.  Keep in mind, if any of the content they are publishing, is public, then you'll be restricting the access of those images and assets to only people assigned in the roles you have selected.  This means any public viewers of your site won't be able to see those assets.

Comment: That's what I did, the list of all libraries still shows and the user can get into them but cannot add folders or files, which is good...  but would prefer that the other libraries not show at all

Comment: Can you give me some more details then as to where they are seeing the "unwanted" libraries @Lawrence?